# format date in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, format

I use the datepicker from jQuery UI, but the format is like example today: **08/01/2013**

But i want the format to be example today: **2013-08-01**

Here is code line i think maybe i should use?

```
`$( "#txtFromDate" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd" );`
```

And here is my jQuery code i use that works fine but don't know where to put the line?
And i want the format in both of my fields.

```
`
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        minDate: "07/17/2012",
        maxDate: "0D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
        }
    });
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: "07/17/2013",
        maxDate:"0D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
        }
    });  
});`
```

I hope somebody have a solution for this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since your already have other options in the datepicker... add it there.

try this

```
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    minDate: "07/17/2012",
    maxDate: "0D",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", //<----here
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it's doesn't work. When i try that, i can't pick any date on the calendar

Comment: `dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" ` should be `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"`

Comment: It's still make the whole calendar unselectable

Comment: i thisnk there is something else that is breaking your code... check your console for any errors

Comment: maybe the problem is minDate and maxDate, should also in format yy-mm-dd.... http://jsfiddle.net/TRqr9/1/

Comment: yes...make sure the `selected` variable is set...  this is not possbile to figure out unless we see all of your codes..

Comment: I found the solution! the problem was when i formatted with `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", //<----here` i forgot to use the format in minDate also.  So thank you to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set the date format from jquery-ui library,that's work for me.hope for you also

in

```
function Datepicker()
{
  //other code
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", // See format options on parseDate 
  //other code
}
```