# jQueryUI Datepicker won't accept different date format

Tags: javascript, html, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepickers made like this:

```
<input id="periode_eind" type="date" class="datepicker" name="periode_eind" value="@Model.PeriodeTotEnMet.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")">
```

They are then converted into [jQueryUI datepickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990584/format-date-in-jquery-ui-datepicker) because native HTML5 datepickers don't support a date format and it needs to always be this format:

```
// Transform native HTML datepickers to jQuery datepickers.
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datepicker = $(".datepicker");
    datepicker.datepicker();
    datepicker.datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', "dd-MM-yyyy");
});
```

I've also tried passing the dateFormat in the constructor as a property, but that doesn't help and it might be too late as the datepickers have already been initialized by the HTML.

Since the value passed to the datepicker is in the wrong format, it produces the following error:

> The specified value "01-05-2016" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

I've also tried to transform to jQuery right away, instead of at the document ready event, but that doesn't help. The jQuery documentation doesn't provide an example with context of how a datepicker is implemented.

How can the datepicker be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the call to `datepicker()` directly to the `class` selector and then use the `dateFormat` option to specify your date format.

---

### Example

```js
$( ".shortYear" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-y'
});

$( ".longYear" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy'
});

$( ".allNumbers" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

$( ".yourRequiredFormat" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-MM-dd'
});
```

```css
/*
  Simple utility classes for example styling
*/
.bordered{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.padded{
  padding: 5px;
}

label span
{
  color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bordered">
  <div class="padded">
    <label> Date (dd-MM-y)</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="shortYear" size="30" >
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="bordered">
  <div class="padded">
    <label> Date (dd-MM-yy)</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="longYear" size="30" >
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="bordered">
  <div class="padded">
    <label> Date (dd-mm-yy)</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="allNumbers" size="30" >
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="bordered">
  <div class="padded">
    <label><span>* Your Required Format</span><br /> Date (yy-MM-dd)</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="yourRequiredFormat" size="30" >
  </div>
</div>
```

`<input>` type should also be `"text"` not `"date"`

```
<input id="periode_eind" type="text" class="datepicker" name="periode_eind" value="@Model.PeriodeTotEnMet.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")">
```

Comment: The important thing here is the input type, which should be text, not date.

Comment: @MrFox Very true, thanks for mentioning that. Will update my answer.